# how to suppress page number for subfigures in LOF?

Tags: tocloft, subcaption

I am using `tocloft` and `subcaption` package, and I would like to suppreess page numbers and dot line for subfigures in LOF.

I know, if one uses `tocloft` and `subfigure` package, this can be done with the next command:

```
\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}
```

So, I would like to emulate this command with `subcaption` package. The point is that I have all the subfigures done with `subcaption` package, and I would not like to change the code of all them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one possibility which enables you to use all of `tocloft` features for subfigure entries when using the `subcaption` package; in particular, you can suppress the page numbers and the leaders (the dots from the entry to the page number):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cftsubtabdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\newcommand\cftsubfigfont{\normalfont}
\newcommand\cftsubfigpresnum{}
\newcommand\cftsubfigaftersnum{}
\newcommand\cftsubfigaftersnumb{}
\newcommand\cftsubfigleader{\hfill}
\newcommand\cftsubfigpagefont{\normalfont}
\newcommand\cftsubfigafterpnum{}
\providecommand{\toclevel@subfigure}{1}
\renewcommand*\l@subfigure[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@lofdepth > \toclevel@subfigure
    \vskip \cftbeforesubfigskip
    {\leftskip \cftsubfigindent\relax
     \rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent \cftsubfigindent\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima \cftsubfignumwidth\relax
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftsubfigpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftsubfigaftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftsubfigaftersnumb
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {\cftsubfigfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftsubfigfillnum{#2}}%
  \fi
  }%
\newlength\cftbeforesubfigskip
  \setlength\cftbeforesubfigskip{\z@ \@plus.2\p@}
\newlength\cftsubfigindent
  \setlength\cftsubfigindent{3.8em}
\newlength\cftsubfignumwidth
  \setlength\cftsubfignumwidth{2.5em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubfigfillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftsubfigleader\hfill}\par
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
A
\caption{test subfigure A}
\label{sfig:testa}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
B
\caption{test subfigure B}
\label{sfig:testb}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Test figure}
\label{fig:testa}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
C
\caption{test subfigure C}
\label{sfig:testc}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
D
\caption{test subfigure D}
\label{sfig:testd}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Test figure}
\label{fig:testb}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The `tocloft` package can offer a bunch of useful macro to tweak the formatting of subfigures if you pass the option `subfigure` to it.

In this case the package will assume that you use the `subfigure` package and that the counters `lofdepth` and `lotdepth` are defined by the subfigure package.

But if you want to use packages `tocloft` with `subcaption` instead of `subfigure` the said counters are not created by `tocloft` nor `subcaption` packages.

Just load the packages and define these counters to make everything works properly.

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\newcounter{lofdepth}
\newcounter{lotdepth}

% here you have access to all tocloft subfig macro
\setlength{\cftsubfigindent}{01emem}
\setlength{\cftsubfignumwidth}{3em}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\ttfamily}
```